# Bootstrap tabs are not accessible Vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, tabs, accessibility, bootstrap-tabs

I have a bootstrap tab working fine the issues is that it is not accessible in a way that while focus is on tabs using arrow keyboard buttons doesn't change focus. This is the code for my tabs:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li
        role="presentation"
        :class="[
            activeSection == 'step-1' ? 'active': '',
            maxStep > 1 ? 'completed': ''
        ]">
        <a
            href="#step-1"
            id="accountInfoTab"
            role="tab"
            tabindex="0"
            aria-controls="accountInfo"
            :aria-expanded="activeSection == 'step-1' ? 'true': 'false'">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li
        role="presentation"
        :class="[
            activeSection == 'step-2' ? 'active': '',
            maxStep > 2 ? 'completed': ''
        ]">
        <a
            href="#step-2"
            id="personalInfoTab"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="personalInfo"
            :aria-expanded="activeSection == 'step-2' ? 'true': 'false'"
            aria-expanded="false"
            :disabled="isDisabled(2)"
            :tabindex="isDisabled(2) ? '-1': '0'">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li
        role="presentation"
        :class="[
            activeSection == 'step-3' ? 'active': '',
            maxStep > 3 ? 'completed': ''
        ]">
        <a
            href="#step-3"
            role="tab"
            id="preferencesTab"
            aria-controls="preferences"
            :aria-expanded="activeSection == 'step-3' ? 'true': 'false'"
            :disabled="isDisabled(3)"
            :tabindex="isDisabled(3) ? '-1': ''">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li
        role="presentation"
        :class="[
            activeSection == 'step-4' || activeSection == 'terms' ? 'active': '',
            maxStep > 4 ? 'completed': ''
        ]">
        <a
          href="#step-4"
          role="tab"
          id="summaryTab"
          aria-controls="summary"
          :aria-expanded="activeSection == 'step-4' ? 'true': 'false'"
          :disabled="isDisabled(4)"
          :tabindex="isDisabled(4) ? '-1': ''">
        </a>
      </li>
</ul>


  <div
    id="registrationFlowTabContent"
    class="tab-content"
    :class="[
        activeSection == 'terms' ? 'wide-content' : '',
        displayAlert ? 'alert-displayed': ''
    ]">
    <!-- accountInfo Tab -->
    <div
        role="tabpanel"
        v-show="activeSection == 'step-1'"
        class="tab-pane fade"
        :class="activeSection == 'step-1'? 'active in': ''"
        id="accountInfo"
        aria-labelledby="accountInfoTab"
        aria-hidden="false"
        aria-expanded="true">
            <!-- some content -->
        </div>

    <!-- personalInfo Tab -->
    <div
        role="tabpanel"
        v-show="activeSection == 'step-2'"
        class="tab-pane fade"
        :class="activeSection == 'step-2'? 'active in': ''"
        id="personalInfo"
        aria-labelledby="personalInfoTab"
        aria-hidden="true"
        aria-expanded="false">
            <!-- some content -->
    </div>

    <!-- preferences Tab -->
    <div
        role="tabpanel"
        v-show="activeSection == 'step-3'"
        :class="activeSection == 'step-3'? 'active in': ''"
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="preferences"
        aria-labelledby="preferencesTab"
        aria-hidden="true"
        aria-expanded="false">
            <!-- some content -->
    </div>

    <!-- summary Tab -->
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      v-show="activeSection == 'step-4'"
      class="tab-pane fade"
      :class="activeSection == 'step-4'? 'active in': ''"
      id="summary"
      aria-labelledby="summaryTab"
      aria-hidden="true"
      aria-expanded="false">
        <!-- some content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript function only disbale/enable the tabs and don't do any accessibility work. So I wanted to know what's a good way to make them accessible? I believe I should implement some eventlisteners, right? If yes how would I do that in Vuejs?

**UPDATE**

Ok so I have added this piece of javascript which makes me enable to navigate between tabs but here is the thing. let's say I'm on first tab. By pressing right arrow key it goes to the next tab which is correct but:

1-If the tab is disabled it shouldn't move the focus to it (which it does).
2-If it next tab is enabled and the focus goes to it after pressing right key arrow I want the content to show immediately. Right now I have to press enter so it shows the content.
3-I want enter key to move the focus on the next focus-able element inside tab panel content instead of selecting that tab.

```
tabAccessibility(){
  var tabs = $("#exTab2");
  var tabsList = tabs.find("ul:first").attr({    
    "role": "tablist"
  });
  $(tabsList).find("li > a").each(
    function() {
      var tab = $(this);
      tab.click(
        function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          tab.focus();
        }
      );
    }
  );
  $(tabsList).delegate("a", "keydown",
    function(e) {

      var tab = $(this);
      switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
        case 38:
          //case 38:
          e.preventDefault();
          if (tab.parent().prev().length !== 0 ) {
            console.log(tab.parent().prev())
            tab.parent().prev().find("> a").click();
          } else {
            console.log(tab.parent().prev())
            $(tabsList).find("li:last > a").click();
          }
          break;
        case 39:
        case 40:
          e.preventDefault();
          if (tab.parent().next().length !== 0) {
            tab.parent().next().find("> a").click();
          } else {
            $(tabsList).find("li:first > a").click();
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: is there any other JS other than enabling / disabling tabs? If so then you need to implement arrow keys to operate with JS by intercepting the `keyDown` and navigate that way. Not got chance to put guidance together today for you but if nobody gives a good answer today I will answer tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks buddy. No the JS only does enabling/disabling. Not anything else. I would appreciate your answer :)

Comment: Please see the edits @GrahamRitchie thanks